# My husband is Japanese but has permanent residency in the UK. I am British. What visa should he apply for to go to Spain?

Tags: visas, spain, japanese-language

We want to move to Spain. What visa does he need to go to Spain? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this should be moved to the Expatriates SE.

Comment: Are you trying to visit Spain or live in Spain?